plaso image_export.py: How to extract $MFT?
How can I extract '$MFT' from E01 disk image using image_export.py which is part of plaso?
The code below didn't work.
$ image_export.py --names '$MFT' win_disk_image.E01

but works for MSDOS.SYS.
$ image_export.py --names MSDOS.SYS win_disk_image.E01

I think I need to escape '$' letter but cannot find out how to.
I am using Windows11, WSL2, Ubuntu, plaso installed via apt.
Thanks in advance.
